# Is there way that I can check if compiled by unreal editor or visual studio?

Tags: c++, game-engine, unreal-engine4

Is there something that I can use like

```
#IF UNREAL_EDITOR

     //Then Excecute some code

#IF VISUAL_STUDIO

  //Then Some Code
```

I want some of my code to be compiled if and only if compiled with Unreal Editor.
Is it possible ?

In Unity there is something like `#IF Unity_Editor` 
Is there something similar to that in Unreal ?

Comment: The visual studio compiler have a [specified set of predefined macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx), most useful for your case might be `_MSC_VER`. You have to read the Unreal Engine documentation yourself to see what, if any, preprocessor macros it defines.

Comment: Steve.. Is that you truly?

Comment: What you meant "Is that truly? "

Comment: He's asking whether you are *that* Steve Jobs, resurrected. I'm pretty sure the answer is "Yes".

Comment: @SteveJobs Your name is `Steve Jobs`, American businessman, entrepreneur and co-founder of Apple computers. He passed away in October 2011, so @FirstStep is asking if you are him, back to ask this question about predefines.

Comment: Long time no see Steve I hope you are **R**esting **I**n **P**eace <3

Comment: I am a ghost, So Be careful :P! lol

Comment: This is my first time seeing ghost asking question on stackoverflow

Comment: Not only humans can pass human verification in stackoverflow , Right?

Comment: Well its strange even after being dead you are being cursed to code wow

Comment: isn't it funny that you get a chance to deal with a genius even after dead ?

Comment: i am dead but still am trying to do as in transcendence movie

Comment: it is funny that i am talking with a ghost,  and anyways i dont think you are genius , dannis was way more intelligent than you

Comment: Don\t start hurting a ghost, I\ll be there when it\s ur turn.....

Comment: i see thanks for the fun mate

Comment: Steve.. Looks like no one likes you on SO .. <3 <3

Comment: @FirstStep, That's sad :P

Comment: Because you acted sick and faked your death but turned out to be programming in **Siri** Lanka? What kind of sorcery is this?? smh ..

Comment: @@FirstStep That's harsh.. Even for ghost!

Comment: yeah @FirstStep you are right, faking death is a crime in itself

Comment: @FirstStep It's called reincarnation :P

Comment: @ankitagrawal  But reincarnation is not a crime :P

Comment: `UE_BUILD_DEVELOPMENT` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

there is

```
#if WITH_EDITOR
```

(yes, better years too late than never)